# Returning a SELECT statement in if condition within stored procedure to c#.net code

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I am a newbie. I am trying to develop a Timesheet Project i which i have a Login page for Employees
where it is same for both the Managers and Developers and when ever Manager Logs in he/She has to see Employee Timesheet. I am using stored procedure to distinguish between Managers and Developers..
Here is the Sp:

```
ALTER Procedure sp_xyz
    @UserName nvarchar(100),
    @Password nvarchar(100)
as
Begin
    Declare @Count int
    Declare @ReturnCode int

    Select @Count = COUNT(EmployeeName) from tblEmployee
    where [EmployeeName] = @UserName and [Password] = @Password

    if(@Count = 1)
    Begin
        --Select 1 as ReturnCode

        exec @ReturnCode = sp_Abc @UserName, @Password
        return 100
    End
    Else
    Begin
        Select -111 as ReturnCode
    End
End 

ALTER PROCEDURE sp_Abc
    @UserName as nvarchar(200),
    @Password as nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @Role as nvarchar(200)

    SELECT @Role = Emp.Role From tblEmployee Emp
    Where Emp.EmployeeName = @UserName and Emp.Password = @Password

    if (@Role = 'Manager')
    Begin
        select
            EmployeeName,
            ProjectName,
            Sunday,
            Monday,
            Tuesday,
            Wednesday,
            Thursday,
            Friday,
            Saturday,
            Week
        from
            tblEmployee
            inner join
                tblProject
            on
                tblProject.ProjectId = tblTimeSheet.ProjectId
            inner join tblTimeSheet
            on
                tblEmployee.EmployeeId = tblTimeSheet.EmployeeId
end
else
    return 10
end
```

My Code:

```
private bool AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
    {

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAuthenticateUsersWhileLogin", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // FormsAuthentication is in System.Web.Security
            string EncryptedPassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, "SHA1");

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", EncryptedPassword);
            var returnParam = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@return",
                Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
            };

            cmd.Parameters.Add(returnParam);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            var ReturnCode = (int)returnParam.Value;
            if (ReturnCode == 100)
            {

                return true; 
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting error.. when i login as developers i am able to view others Timesheet which i don want to.. I don know wher i am going wrong...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting..?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks for info i ll surely change my stored procedure name.

Comment: also just use a single line do declare the new SqlParameter for your output for example 
`SqlParameter returnParam = new SqlParameter("@return", SqlDbType.Int);` change the SqlType to the correct type if it's not an SqlType.Int

Comment: The code is not working rite. when i login as manager i should be able to view employee timesheet and if i login as developers it should navigate to a different page

Comment: It's 2014, why are people still writing data access code like this?

Comment: because if they are from a `3rd world` country they have not caught up with the times nor could they afford something more robust is my guess.. or their employer is `TOOO CHEAP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to separate your login logic from your Role Logic 
because right now (at least from what you're showing us) 
the only thing that you are checking in the C# code is if the 
user exists in the base

```
 var ReturnCode = (int)returnParam.Value;
        if (ReturnCode == 100)
        {

            return true; 
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

so what you need to do after this is call the second Stored procedure

```
  //.....call of sp_Abc
 if (ReturnCodeAbc == 10) //10 means is not manager
        {

            // do some logic 
        }
        else
        {
           //do the manager stuff
        }
```